# Binded Propertys' Setter called before View finished Loading

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, properties, initialization

I'm currently developing in WPF (Surface 2.0) and using the MVVM pattern for most parts of my application. I am, unfortunately, currently facing a rather complicated issue I hope you guys can assist me on:

I have a View and a ViewModel that belongs to it. The View contains a two-way binding to a property in the ViewModel:

```
<pb:PivotBar ItemsSource="{Binding PivotBarEntries}" 
SelectedItemIndex="{Binding SelectedPivotItemIndex, Mode=TwoWay}" />

(...)

<local:SomeOtherView />
```

While the View is first loaded, the setter of SelectedPivotItemIndex is called. This is fine, except that the setter is called before the rest of the view loaded. Since the setter sends messages (via MVVMLight's Messenger) to other viewmodels that are created later in the view, this is a problem - those messages never reach their destination since no receiver is registered for them so far.

```
public int SelectedPivotItemIndex
{
    get
    {
        return this.selectedPivotItemIndex;
    }
    set
    {
        if (value != this.selectedPivotItemIndex)
        {
            this.selectedPivotItemIndex = value;
            this.ReportPropertyChanged("SelectedPivotItemIndex");

            (...)

            ChangeSomeOtherViewModelProperty msg = new ChangeSomeOtherViewModelProperty { Property = newValueCalculatedBefore };
            Messenger.Default.Send<ChangeSomeOtherViewModelProperty>(msg);
        }
    }
}
```

The only solution I can think of right now, would be to create a LoadedEventHandler in the ViewModel and call the SelectedPivotItemIndex setter *again*. I don't really like that, though:

- For once, the setter runs again (which creates a rather large collection that is passed to the message). Don't know if it would really impact performance, but still seems unnecessary.
- Secondly, it just seems kind of hackish and error prone to me, since every property has to be initialized manually in the loaded event.

Is there any solution to this problem better than just manually calling the setter?

Comment: Firstly, are changes to the SelectedPivotItemIndex in the view being reflected in the ViewModel i.e is the two way binding working correctly? and can you show us a sample of the code you use to register for messages in other classes?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. Yes, the code is working - the setter is called (checked via breakpoint). Also, the message registering is done very simple: In the constructor: `Messenger.Default.Register< MessageName>(this, (msg) => ReceivedMessage(msg));`. And somewhere later: `private void ReceivedMessage(MessageName msg) { ... }`. The message receiving is working as well - again, when I send the message in the loaded event it works fine!

Comment: Have you tried using the DispatcherHelper class to make sure it doesn't require invoking. Look [here](http://chriskoenig.net/2010/07/05/mvvm-light-messaging/), and try     Messenger.Default.Register<PropertyChangedMessage<Person>>(
        this,
        (action) => DispatcherHelper.CheckBeginInvokeOnUI( () => this.Item = action.NewValue )
    );

Comment: use viewmodel first approach and your problems are gone :)

Comment: Unfortunately, the DispatcherHelper doesn't seem to work - since the register-code is executed after the message send code, this doesn't help. I think there needs to be something done on the sending side. As for the viewmodel first approach: Do you have any tutorials on that? I'm not really sure how to implement that. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i dont have a tutorial for viewmodel first, but i'm sure the are a lot examples out there. viewmodel first is nothing more then you have the viewmodel instance first and then let wpf create the view(via datatemplate).

let say your mainview should show a view with your PivotBarEntries. so what you do now is to create a pivotbarviewmodel in your mainviewmodel (DI, MEF, new() what ever). your mainviewmodel expose the pivotvw as a property and bind it to a ContentPresenter.Content in your mainview. at least you have to create a DataTemplate for your pivotvw DataType.

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:PivotViewModel>
 <view:MyPivotView/>
</DataTemplate>
```

thats about viewmodel first, you do not rely on load events on view anymore, because your vm is created first.

of course for your specific problem you just have to be sure that all your components(VM's) which listen to your messenger should be created

your xaml

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding MyPivotDataVM}" />
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding MySomeOtherStuffVM}" />
```

instead of view first

```
<pb:PivotBar ItemsSource="{Binding PivotBarEntries}" 
SelectedItemIndex="{Binding SelectedPivotItemIndex, Mode=TwoWay}" />

(...)

<local:SomeOtherView />
```

**EDIT: very simple example for viewmodel first.** ps: i use DI with MEF to create my object path.

app.xaml

```
<Application x:Class="WpfViewModelFirst.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:WpfViewModelFirst="clr-namespace:WpfViewModelFirst">
<!--StartUp Uri is removed-->
<Application.Resources>
    <!--comment these datatemplates and see what happens-->
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type WpfViewModelFirst:PivotViewModel}">
        <WpfViewModelFirst:PivotView/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type WpfViewModelFirst:OtherViewModel}">
        <WpfViewModelFirst:OtherView/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type WpfViewModelFirst:OtherChildViewModel}">
        <WpfViewModelFirst:OtherChildView/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

app.xaml.cs

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        //to be fair, sometimes i create the ApplicationRoot(JUST MainWindow with view first, and just the rest with viewmodel first.)
        var mainvm = new MainViewModel();
        var mainview = new MainWindow {DataContext = mainvm};
        this.MainWindow = mainview;
        this.MainWindow.Show();
    }
}
```

mainview.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfViewModelFirst.MainWindow" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>        
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyProp}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="0"/>        
    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding MyPivot}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" />
    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding MyOther}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" />        
</Grid>
</Window>
```

mainviewmodel.cs

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    public string MyProp { get; set; }
    public PivotViewModel MyPivot { get; set; }
    public OtherViewModel MyOther { get; set; }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        this.MyProp = "Main VM";
        this.MyPivot = new PivotViewModel();
        this.MyOther = new OtherViewModel();
    }
}
```

PivotViewmodel

```
public class PivotViewModel
{
    public string MyProp { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<string> MyList { get; set; }

    public PivotViewModel()//Dependency here with constructor injection
    {
        this.MyProp = "Test";
        this.MyList = new ObservableCollection<string>(){"Test1", "Test2"};
    }
}
```

OtherViewmodel

```
public class OtherViewModel
{
    public string MyProp { get; set; }
    public OtherChildViewModel MyChild { get; set; }

    public OtherViewModel()
    {
        this.MyProp = "Other Viewmodel here";
        this.MyChild = new OtherChildViewModel();
    }
}
```

OtherChildViewmodel

```
public class OtherChildViewModel
{
    public string MyProp { get; set; }

    public OtherChildViewModel()//Dependency here with constructor injection
    {
        this.MyProp = "Other Child Viewmodel";
    }
}
```

PivotView

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfViewModelFirst.PivotView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyProp}" Grid.Row="0"/>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}" Grid.Row="1"/>
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

OtherView

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfViewModelFirst.OtherView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition  />
        <RowDefinition  />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyProp}" Grid.Row="0" />
    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding MyChild}" Grid.Row="1"/>
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

OtherChildView

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfViewModelFirst.OtherChildView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyProp}" />
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Thank you for the nice response. One follow-up question though: Wouldn't this violate MVVM? In this scenario, mainviewmodel creates pivotbarviewmodel which then in turn has to crete pivotbarview - but in MVVM, the viewmodel should not know about its view, afaik. Am I overseeing something here?

Comment: the viewmodel know nothing about the view and it dont care. the pivotviewmodel(pvm) did not create the view. the mainviewmodel simple say to wpf show my pvm with the binding i made in the contentpresenter. now wpf asks "how to render your viewmodel? then you said :) look at Resources i defined a datatemplate how to render my pvm. the wpf says ok its done. i display your pivotview in the contentpresenter with the datacontext binding to pvm. your bindings works now.i hope you see that the viewmodel has no referenc at all to the view.any questions let me know. i always use vmfirst in my projects.

Comment: can you post the code where you set the datacontext of your pivot view and SomeOtherView. then i can update my example

Comment: my approach is to create the viewmodel in the XAML files, so basically in every view-XAML I do this (with "ViewBase" being the baseclass of my view): `<local:ViewBase.DataContext>
  <local:MyViewModel x:Name="Model" />
 </local:ViewBase.DataContext>`

Comment: that classic view first. i will add a very simple viewmodel first example. btw if you do viewmmodel first, just dont think of your views :)

Comment: thanks for this, solved the problem! by the way: technically, my main VM can now communicate directly with, for example, the pivot VM instead of through a messaging service. should this be done or should VMs still communicate through messages?

Comment: it depends :) if communicate directly you loose some sort of "loose coupling" between your viewmodels.