# MVVM, The best way to structure the View

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have made a root AppView, a root AppViewModel for my application as a container for all the things. Within the application view, I have a TabControl that each tab has its own task to do. One tab for imoprting data, one tab for issuing, one tab for management and etc:

```
App_View[Model] // root
{ 
   TabTask1_View[Model], TabTask2_View[Model], TabTask3_View[Model] // tab items
}
```

1) In MVVM, Is it standard that I have grouped my whole views and view-models into the main application-view and application-model-view ?

2) In MVVM, The model should be implemented for every view & vm ? Or is it standard if I implement the whole models into one or two class files and share the model between them? I personally think that model part is not specific to a certain view, like the class 'student' that can be used anywhere in the code and is not restricted to a certain view. Based on this, if the models are general and shared, yet, is it good to follow the naming convention Class + 'Model' for it? like StudentModel? Is it helpful/necessary to add 'Model' after the general or shared class name like the thing I said?

3) In WPF, What is the best way to implement the Views? I want to edit and design very easily and without any restriction, and it should be standard enough to cover future needs. There are 4 things to use: Window, Page, UserControl and DataTemplate. Which one is the best option that you go for? UserControl or Page?

4) In WPF, How can I load the UserControl/Page(View) inside a tabItem dynamically at run-time based on the MVVM approach?

Comment: 4) i use viewmodel-first approach in my project. look at my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10905918/binded-propertys-setter-called-before-view-finished-loading/10911863#10911863  the Edit part has an example

Comment: 3) Window and DataTemplates, DataTemplates a lot, and propably a lot of Styles, ControlTemplates etc. Try to minimize the amount of UserControls (personally i don't like them and avoid them whenever possible) organize them in ResourceDictionary xamls and place all of them in your app.xaml

Comment: @dowhilefor what you have against UserControls ? most of them are empty in code behind that's true but dues it hurt that much?

Comment: I don't see the point in them to be honest. We barely use them, also if you handled your resourcedictionaries wrong UserControls are very memory expensive. I also consider the code behind concept difficult to maintain. Besides that in our app, we have a customized look and feel another thing UserControls aren't good at. In the end its propably personal preference, but i never have the desire or the need to use a UserControl, except Window of course.

Comment: @dowhilefor I think they're all useful in their right places. There are some situations that we need to design using windows and some situations we need to use templates and controls. So it varies. I personally haven't tested the speed and memory consumption, so I cannot accept or reject the thing that user-controls are memory wasters. Might be right/wrong. But I think it varies by how and where and for what we use them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're cheating.  That's 4 questions!

1)

In terms of how you group your Views and Viewmodels I've seen people put views and viewmodels in the same namespace/folder and others separate them out into different folders based on functionality.  The best option for you is what suits you/your team.  There is no "right" way.

2)

Keep it DRY - so don't repeat yourself.  It is perfectly sensible to reuse code.  If you have common classes keep them common.  As for naming, the name of the class should be helpful in explaining what it does:  I'm sure you'd be able to figure out what the classes NavigationService, NavigationMenuItem and NavigationMenuView did and probably could put together a good mental model of how they relate.  So - if naming a class BlahViewModel or BlahModel is useful to you, do it.

3) Implementing views:

A Window is always shown independently.  Pages are intended for use in Navigation applications (usually with Back and Forward buttons, e.g. Internet Explorer). Pages must be hosted in a NavigationWindow or a Frame. If you're looking at dynamically adding/removing content, adding content to ItemsControls (TabControl, etc) then you'll want to be creating user controls.  You can put user controls in Page and Window object, into other controls, etc, and are really the workhorse for WPF developers.

4)

You have a number of options here:

1)The quick and dirty way is to create DataTemplate which, on being given a ViewModel of type X, load up and apply the ViewModel to their data context.  This will allow you to inject a ViewModel directly into a control and have the correct View render.

An example:

View.xaml

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding Error, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

ViewModel:

```
        private void ReceiveError(ErrorViewModel errorModel)
        {
            //if (errorModel.AcceptCommand==null || errorModel.AcceptCommand is NoOpCommand)
            errorModel.AcceptCommand = new DelegateCommand(ClearError);
            Error = errorModel;
        }
public ErrorViewModel Error
        {
            get { return _error; }
            set
            {
                _error = value;


                _propertyChangedHelper.NotifyPropertyChanged(this, () => Error);
            }
        }
```

Styles.Xaml (ResourceDictionary)

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:ErrorViewModel}">

        <DataTemplate.Resources>
            <conv:CustomisableBooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="VisibilityConverter" TrueValue="Visible" FalseValue="Collapsed" />
        </DataTemplate.Resources>
        <Popup AllowsTransparency="True" PopupAnimation="Fade" Placement="Center"  StaysOpen="True"
               PlacementTarget="{Binding Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type v:ModuleView}}}"
               IsOpen="True" Width="400" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"/>
```

So you can see I'm injecting my viewmodel directly into the content control and it's using the data template that is bound to the viewmodel's type to find a View for it.

2)

A better bet is to use a DataTemplateSelector.  This basically allows you to specify which templates are available for a control and then uses logic you code to determine which datatemplate to use.  You can find an example of this [here](http://tech.pro/tutorial/807/wpf-tutorial-how-to-use-a-datatemplateselector).

3)

Use a framework that abstracts the UI controls away.  Microsoft has a framework (free) that does this called Prism.  Basically, instead of adding your usercontrols directly to a TabControl,ItemsControl, etc you add your control to a named "Region".  This region is mapped to an underlying control and an adaptor is put in place to manage how that UserContorl is added/removed when you ask it to be.  You can find an in-depth discussion of this [here](http://www.developmentalmadness.com/archive/2009/10/14/mvvm-and-prism-101-ndash-part-3-regions.aspx).  Beware, though, Prism is an application framework so implementing this isn't 3 hours work.

Comment: It was very helpful, thanks so much. Actually I bundled the related questions in one package thinking it's better to keep the website compact and clean.;)

Answer (score 1):

Here is not an answer, it's my experience that i'll explain to you and how I handle with MVVM. I started with WPF 3 month ago and I handle with it.

1. For each new theme/menue/option I create a new project file wich contains the ViewModels and the Views. All Business classes are collected in one Project file because I may have to use it in more than one ViewModel.
2. Yes, it was helpful for me as beginner to name the the classes ...ViewModel and ..View. It maked it easy for me to separate the diffrences and also it was/is easier to explain other people your classes ( for example if u have a problem with your coding )
3. I am using UserControls for our different views and I load them into ContentControls and TabControls without any problems.
4. Have a look at Prism for MVVM-pattern.

Comment: Thank you so much dennis, your suggestions helped me alot.

Answer (score 1):

**Point 1:**

It depends. There are two widely used approaches AFAIK. First is as you've said group all VM's that constitute the same `Window` with direct dependencies to form a class structure that shows your actual program structure. Second is where you use an `EventAggregator`(Prism) / `Messenger`(MVVM Light) to loosely link the VM's instead of direct dependency.

Now both approaches have their benefit's

- With the first one It's pretty easy to identify your program structure cos your VM dependencies show it clearly, which is not so clearly visible from the second approach.
- Second approach helps you a lot when unit testing VM's cos you are not forced to either mock / work-around all the dependent VM's, It also helps code re-factoring a bit when changing project structure(think of "Plug in" classes)

oh and these ^^ are by no means exclusive. You can mix these together well and fine.

**Point 2:**

Models do not have any recommended 1 <-> 1 relation with a View / VM like what Views have with VM. Models just hold your Business Logic. I've had apps that sometimes do not hold a Model at all. Something there is just 1 Model used by the entire Application(when the back-end is say a c++ library and you just interface with it with a C++/CLI Module). yes maintain the naming convention to append Model class names with "Model"

**Point 3**

How about all of them? use them where applicable. Do not take a partial preference to any. When a View composes multiple other sections that are by themselves a View with VM I'd have a `DataTemplate` with the Data a `UserControl`. Your app almost always uses a Window and `Page` is useful for navigation based apps I think. Think `Page`'s are what I've used least tbh.

**Point 4**

This is a question of tutorial's. Take a bunch of examples, see how it's implemented, reason it and pick your approach. If your using VS2010 get [MVVM In the box](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3ab5f02f-0c54-453c-b437-8e8d57eb9942) (It's great. no 2 ways about that. Really hope this could get to be updated for VS2012 if it's not already). For VS2012 check out [Two Views MVVM CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/323187/MVVMLight-Using-Two-Views) which shows the concept, you can then apply it to any `ItemsControl` of your choosing.

Finally atleast when you're starting up, **PLEASE** start off with using a MVVM helper library. I prefer [MVVM Light](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/) <- that link has a couple videos by the author of the library showing some usages and you can find extensive help here on SO about it. If you want to do things yourself, learn the basics from it and then implement it yourself. if you take the high road from day-one it's just a much longer learning curve(Just my opinion)

Comment: Thank you so much, if I could flag two answers I would mark this as an answer too.